# iterating collections in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a class that has this code,

```
pCollection pub = RSSXmlDeserializer.GetPub(path, fReload);
```

Get pub is the method that returns a collections of pub's...

How can I iterate them. I tried,

```
for (var n = 0; n < pub.Count; n++) {
}
```

this is the getPub method

```
    public static PCollection GetPub(string path, bool fReload)
    {
        HttpApplicationState session = HttpContext.Current.Application;

        PCollection pub = session["PUB"] as PCollection;

        if pub == null || fReload)
        {
            StreamReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PCollection));
                reader = new StreamReader(path);
                pub = (PCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                session["PUB"] = pub;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        return pub;
    }
}


[Serializable()]
public class Pub
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("imageUrl")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("RPublications")]
public class PCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Pub")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Pub", typeof(Pub))]
    public Pub[] Pub { get; set; }
}
```

but 'Count' is not recognised. I get this message, pCollection does not have a definition for 'Count'...

How do I iterate the collection n get the collection elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PCollection` is not really a collection. It is a class that contains a collection (more precisely an array). So to iterate you need to iterate the array:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < pub.Pub.Length; ++i) {
  Pub p = pub.Pub[i];
  ...
}
```

Or if you don't care about the index and just want to go through the collection from start to finish:

```
foreach (Pub p in pub.Pub) {
  ...
}
```

(A more consistent naming of types and members would probably help.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
foreach(var p in pub.Pub)
{
     // Do work on p
}
```

Note that your `PCollection` class is not following good .NET practices, as it's named "Collection" but not implementing any of the standard interfaces for collections.  You may want to consider reworking this to be more "standardized".